# Python, Pandas: Error while creating a new column with datetime

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

Good day,

inside my dataframe there's a column with items from type <class 'datetime.time'>. The first item contains the following data:

```
17:06:37.175539
```

When executing the following code...

```
hour = df['time'][0].hour
```

I'll be getting the expected value: 17. But when trying to execute this for my whole dataframe...

```
df['hour'] = df['time'].hour
```

...the following error occurs: **'Series' object has no attribute 'hour'**!

Can someone tell me, what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks to all of you!

Comment: Use `df['hour'] = df['time'].dt.hour`

Comment: @jezrael Now I'm getting the following error: 'Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values'

Comment: Use `df['hour'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time']).dt.hour`

Comment: Followed the link and used a lambda-expression: `df['hour'] = df['time'].apply(lambda x: x.hour)`. It's working, just like your second solution! Thanks for your help!